# Python - add functionality to function to access information from previous call

Tags: python, caching, func

I got a function like below:

```
def my_func(some_objects):
    objects_information = []
    for object_ in some_objects:
        object_information = dict()
        object_information['name'] = some_object.name
        object_information['position'] = some_object.position
        object_information['previous_position'] = previous_position or None
        objects_information.append(object_information)
    return objects_information
```

how can I add to that function an option to hold information about the objects position so in the line `object_information['previous_position']` I can use the information `object_position['position']` from the last call to the function?  If `object_information['name']` is the same as in previous call and if it's the first call with that object_name it will place None in previous_position key.

Thank you very much

Comment: Looks like you should write a class

Comment: I don't want  to write a class for it :) i need to add functionality to that function, with some decorator or w/e :)

Comment: then abuse the mutable default argument and use `my_func(some_objects, objects_information = [])`, but don't show the code to anyone

Comment: will do that way thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> functionality to function to access information from previous call

To get such feature you might exploit [mutable default argument gotcha](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments), consider following example

```
def remember(arg, seen=[]):
    seen.append(arg)
    return seen
print(remember(3))
print(remember(5))
print(remember(7))
```

output

```
[3]
[3, 5]
[3, 5, 7]
```

Note that this is often trap for `python` coders unaware of this behavior, so if you decide to use it document it well.

Comment: The clean way, of course, is to write a class with a `__call__` method and an instance variable `seen`.